# Using WebClient in C# is there a way to get the URL of a site after being redirected?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, http

Using the WebClient class I can get the title of a website easily enough:

```
WebClient x = new WebClient();    
string source = x.DownloadString(s);
string title = Regex.Match(source, 
    @"\<title\b[^>]*\>\s*(?<Title>[\s\S]*?)\</title\>",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups["Title"].Value;
```

I want to store the URL and the page title. However when following a link such as:

http://tinyurl.com/dbysxp

I'm clearly going to want to get the Url I'm redirected to.

**QUESTIONS**

Is there a way to do this using the `WebClient` class?

How would I do it using `HttpResponse` and `HttpRequest`?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

If I understand the question, it's much easier than people are saying - if you want to let WebClient do all the nuts and bolts of the request (including the redirection),  but then get the *actual* response URI at the end, you can subclass WebClient like this:

```
class MyWebClient : WebClient
{
    Uri _responseUri;

    public Uri ResponseUri
    {
        get { return _responseUri; }
    }

    protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
    {
        WebResponse response = base.GetWebResponse(request);
        _responseUri = response.ResponseUri;
        return response;
    }
}
```

Just use MyWebClient everywhere you would have used WebClient.  After you've made whatever WebClient call you needed to do, then you can just use ResponseUri to get the actual redirected URI.  *You'd need to add a similar override for GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result) too, if you were using the async stuff.*

Comment: This won't work if you're downloading async (e.g., using `DownloadStringAsync`), but it works great for synchronous calls.

Comment: Why didn't you just suggest doing what you did in the overrided method instead of extending the whole class lol ?

Comment: @GabrielBB - GetWebResponse is protected, so you can't get to it except within a subclass of WebClient.

Comment: Brilliant! Works very well.

Answer (score 17):

I know this is already an answered question, but this works pretty to me:

```cs
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://tinyurl.com/dbysxp");
 request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
 HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
 string redirUrl = response.Headers["Location"];
 response.Close();

 //Show the redirected url
 MessageBox.Show("You're being redirected to: "+redirUrl);
```

Cheers.! ;)

Comment: It's essential to to finally call `response.close()` (or to use a `using` statement). See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse(v=vs.110).aspx for details. Otherwise you may run out of connections or get a timeout when executing this code multiple times.

Comment: Isn't AllowAutoRedirect false by default? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.httpwebclientprotocol.allowautoredirect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Hello Mick! The link you posted is for WebClient's AllowAutoRedirect. I searched for HttpWebRequest and found that AllowAutoRedirect is true by default! lol! I don't know why! But in this example I'm instantiating WebRequest not WebClient https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect(v=vs.110).aspx Cheers

Comment: This is a good idea, as long as the first redirect does not go to subsequent redirects - which is not unthinkable.

Answer (score 6):

With an [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx), you would set the [`AllowAutoRedirect` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect.aspx) to `false`.  When this happens, any response with a status code between 300-399 will not be automatically redirected.

You can then get the new url from the response headers and then create a new `HttpWebRequest` instance to the new url.

With the [`WebClient` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx), I doubt you can change it out-of-the-box so that it does not allow redirects.  What you could do is derive a class from the `WebClient` class and then override the [`GetWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.getwebrequest.aspx) and the [`GetWebResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3xa6ys0.aspx) methods to alter the [`WebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx)/[`WebResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse.aspx) instances that the base implementation returns; if it is an `HttpWebRequest`, then set the `AllowAutoRedirect` property to `false`.  On the response, if the status code is in the range of 300-399, then issue a new request.

However, I don't know that you can issue a new request from within the `GetWebRequest`/`GetWebResponse` methods, so it might be better to just have a loop that executes with `HttpWebRequest`/[`HttpWebResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx) until all the redirects are followed.

Comment: Any chance you can give an example of how you would do this?

Answer (score 3):

I got the Uri for the redirected page and the page contents.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strUrl);
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

strLastRedirect = response.ResponseUri.ToString();

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);              
string strResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();

response.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you are only interested in the redirect URI you can use this code:

```
public static string GetRedirectUrl(string url)
{
     HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
     request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

     using (HttpWebResponse response = HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
     {
         return response.Headers["Location"];
     }
}
```

The method will return

- null - in case of no redirect
- a relative url - in case of a redirect

**Please note**: The `using` statement (or a final `response.close()`) is essential. See [MSDN Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse(v=vs.110).aspx) for details. Otherwise you may run out of connections or get a timeout when executing this code multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

HttpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect can be set to false.  Then you'd have to manually http status codes in the 300 range.

```
// Create a new HttpWebRequest Object to the mentioned URL.
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest=(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com");    
myHttpWebRequest.MaximumAutomaticRedirections=1;
myHttpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect=true;
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse=(HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score -1):

The WebClient class has an option to follow redirects. Set that option and you should be fine.

Answer (score -1):

Ok this is really hackish, but the key is to use the HttpWebRequest and then set the AllowAutoRedirect property to true.

Here's a VERY hacked together example

```
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://tinyurl.com/dbysxp");
        req.Method = "GET";
        req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();

        response.GetResponseStream();
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        // Content-Length header is not trustable, but makes a good hint.
        // Responses longer than int size will throw an exception here!
        int length = (int)response.ContentLength;

        const int bufSizeMax = 65536; // max read buffer size conserves memory
        const int bufSizeMin = 8192;  // min size prevents numerous small reads

        // Use Content-Length if between bufSizeMax and bufSizeMin
        int bufSize = bufSizeMin;
        if (length > bufSize)
            bufSize = length > bufSizeMax ? bufSizeMax : length;

        StringBuilder sb;
        // Allocate buffer and StringBuilder for reading response
        byte[] buf = new byte[bufSize];
        sb = new StringBuilder(bufSize);

        // Read response stream until end
        while ((length = responseStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length)) != 0)
            sb.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf, 0, length));

        string source = sb.ToString();string title = Regex.Match(source, 
        @"\<title\b[^>]*\>\s*(?<Title>[\s\S]*?)\</title\>",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups["Title"].Value;
```

`enter code here`