# C# WebClient OpenRead url

Tags: c#, webclient

So I have this program that fetches a page using a short link (I used Google url shortener).
To build my example I used code from [Using WebClient in C# is there a way to get the URL of a site after being redirected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690587/using-webclient-in-c-is-there-a-way-to-get-the-url-of-a-site-after-being-redirec)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyWebClient client = new MyWebClient();
            client.OpenRead("http://tinyurl.com/345yj7x");            
            Uri uri = client.ResponseUri;            
            Console.WriteLine(uri.AbsoluteUri);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    class MyWebClient : WebClient
    {
        Uri _responseUri;

        public Uri ResponseUri
        {
            get { return _responseUri; }
        }

        protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
        {
            WebResponse response = base.GetWebResponse(request);
            _responseUri = response.ResponseUri;
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

I do not understant a thing: when I do `client.OpenRead("http://tinyurl.com/345yj7x");` this downloads the page that the url points to? If this method downloads the page, I need something to get me only the url, so if there's a method to get only some headers, or only the url, please let me know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get the headers only using a HEAD request, like this:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(sourceUri);
request.Method = "HEAD";

var response = request.GetResponse();
if (response != null) {
    // You can now use response.Headers to get header info
}
```

Comment: Bullseye. Then just use response.ResponseUri to get your URL - in this case it looks to be "http://www.google.ro/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=c%23+webclient+tinyurl"

Comment: Added using on response otherwise you leave the connection open. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46832502/1087922

Answer (score 3):

Create a [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) with the [AllowAutoRedirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect.aspx) property set to false, then look at the [Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpresponseheader.aspx) header on the response.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://tinyurl.com/345yj7x");
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
var response = request.GetResponse();
var location = response.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.Location];
```