# Using HttpClient, how would I prevent automatic redirects and get original status code and forwading Url in the case of 301

Tags: c#, http, redirect, httpclient

I have the following method that returns the `Http status code` of a given `Url`:

```
public static async void makeRequest(int row, string url)
{
    string result;
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch(); sw.Start();

    try
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            response = await client.GetAsync(url);

            // dump contents of header
            Console.WriteLine(response.Headers.ToString());

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                result = ((int)response.StatusCode).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                result = ((int)response.StatusCode).ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException hre)
    {
        result = "Server unreachable";
    }

    sw.Stop();
    long time = sw.ElapsedTicks / (Stopwatch.Frequency / (1000L * 1000L));

    requestComplete(row, url, result, time);
}
```

It works well for `200`/`404` etc, however in the case of `301` codes I believe the returned result is the *already-redirected* (`200`) result, rather than the actual `301` that should be returned and which would have a header containing where the redirect would be pointed to.

I have seen something like this in other .Net web requests classes and the technique there was to set some sort of `allowAutoRedirect` property to false. If this is along the right lines, can anyone tell me the correct alternative for the `HttpClient` class?

[This post has info on the above allowAutoRedirect concept I mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690587/using-webclient-in-c-sharp-is-there-a-way-to-get-the-url-of-a-site-after-being-r)

Else, how might I get this method to return `301s` rather than `200s` for Urls I know to be genuine `301s`?

Comment: How do you know that the exception means that the server is unreachable?

Comment: I don't, but that's the best my abilities will allow for the mean time.

Comment: Do your abilities permit you to display the exception somewhere, by outputting `hre.ToString()`?

Comment: Haha, well clearly not. No good shout. It was more of a catch all approach for the mean time but I will further dissect the exceptions and implement proper handling.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I have found that the way to do this is by creating an instance of [`HttpClientHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler?view=netframework-4.7) and passing it in the constructor of `HttpClient`

```
public static async void makeRequest(int row, string url)
{
    string result;
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch(); sw.Start();

    // added here
    HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
    httpClientHandler.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

    try
    {
        // passed in here
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
        {

        }
```

See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/08/07/httpclient-httpclienthandler-and-httpwebrequesthandler.aspx) for more info.

Comment: But settings AllowAutoRedirect to flase means you have to manually handle each 3XX cases. There is no way to only alter 301 case.

Comment: In fact, you have to handle manually 301, 302, 303 and 307.

Comment: By the way, you wrapped HttpClient in a using statement, but the HttpClientHandler needs to be disposed too.

Comment: FYI - you should not create a new instance of `HttpClient` for each request.  This will lead to performance issues at scale.  See [this guidance](https://github.com/mspnp/performance-optimization/blob/master/ImproperInstantiation/docs/ImproperInstantiation.md) from Microsoft patterns & practices.

Comment: @MattJohnson That link is now a 404. I think this is (now) : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/architecture/antipatterns/improper-instantiation/